# What pattern is best suited for executing different actions (depending on user input) in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

I want to write a program in **python** that the user will be able to decide what operation will run at runtime, but also I want to make my program designed well in order to be able to add operations easily.
lets say the user inputs "3 4 add"
then the output would be 7
and if he write "3 4 mul"
then the output would be 12.

please note that i'm not looking for the traditional "if, elif, elif" ect,
because I want to make a design that will allow other programmers to easily add operations.

what pattern should I use, and any tips/guide on how to implement it?

**Edit :** just to make sure I've explained myself, the other programmers would not have access to the code of the main program, but they should still be able to add different actions to the program.

thanks.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: Use a dictionary to translate the word and use reverse Polish notation.

Comment: @Mohit Bhasi I tried visitor pattern but I'm not sure its the situation here, since the other programmers will not have access to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator

# custom function 

def diff_squares(a, b):
    return a ** 2 - b ** 2

operators = {'add' : operator.add,
             'sub' : operator.sub,
             'mul' : operator.mul,
             'div' : operator.div,
             'dos' : diff_squares}

data = raw_input('Question: ')
data = data.split()

a = int(data[0]) # one number
b = int(data[1]) # two number

answer = operators[data[2]](a, b)
print 'Solution:', answer
```

Comment: thanks alot, but I'm looking for something a bit more custom, lets say, what if I want the programmer to be able to add a custom functions word? (not just plain 'add')

Comment: You can add keys and values to the dictionary. It's that simple, let me add an example.

Comment: You see that ori? Now you can add custom functions to your dictionary!

Comment: thanks again! now lets say this whole code was written by me in "prog.py" file, and I want another programmer to come and add a function, without any access to my "prog.py" file, is that even possible? or would I have to use an external file (such as txt or something similar) that my prog.py will read the functions from?

Comment: Yes, you can import the other programmer's functions and add them to the dictionary. Do you mind marking as answer?

Comment: I will defenately do that when my question is answered - thank you ! I'm still missing one thing - I want a design that will allow OTHER programmer, that DONT have access to my code, be able to add their own functions. any ideas? (thanks again)

Comment: For example, I send my .py file to a fellow programmer, I want him to create another .py file with another class that will inherit an abstract class that I wrote, implementing a function called 'operate' that will now do the operation that he chose to write. the problem is, how can it be integrated to my old code?